# Реализация стохастического растрирования

Tags: java, алгоритм, изображения

Необходимо перевести обычное изображение в формат, где оттенки серого будут передаваться частотой черных точек.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Точки должны быть одинаковыми, круглыми. На выходе необходимо получить матрицу этих точек. В идеале цветной пример бы, но разобраться бы сначала с чб.

Нашел информацию, что это называется в печати частотно-модулированное растрирование. Как можно реализовать этот алгоритм? Где искать информацию? Планирую писать на Java.

Comment: Для каждой точки посчитать в её окрестности средний фон, а потом перевести его в процент. А у меня интереснее вопрос: а как это потом отрисовать?

Comment: Floyd-Steinberg dithering

Comment: Так в чем задача именно? Сделать любой дизеринг? Или сделать какой-то особо  красивый дизеринг? Обычный построчный алгоритм с накоплением ошибки сделает вам дизеринг, но будет не так красиво.

Comment: @AnT Да, дизеринг именно то что мне нужно. Спасибо, наконец узнал как это правильно называется

Comment: Это называется дизеринг, в интернете много уроков есть. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0L2n8Tg2FwI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для поля вида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

обыкновенный построчный дизеринг с горизонтальным переносом ошибки

```
int main()
{
  const int S = 300; // Размер поля
  const int R = 256; // Диапазон яркостей

  for (int y = 0; y < S; ++y)
  {
    int error = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < S; ++x)
    {
      int ideal = (x + y) * (R - 1) / (2 * (S - 1));
      int corrected = ideal + error;
      int bw = corrected < R / 2 ? 0 : R - 1;
      error = corrected - bw;

      // Исходное поле: нарисовать точку (x, y) с яркостью `ideal`
      // Дизеринг: нарисовать точку (x, y) с яркостью `bw`
    }
  }
}
```

дает следующую картину

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(узор будет зависеть от размеров изображения). А уж нужно ли вам что-то более хитрое - вам решать.

---

Чисто ради интереса:

То же самое, построчно, но со сменой направлений "туда-сюда" и с глобальным распространением ошибки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Незамысловатый однонаправленный дизеринг вдоль диагоналей из левого нижнего в правый верхний

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дизеринг вокруг концентрических квадратов, из левого нижнего угла против часовой стрелки, с глобальным распространением ошибки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То же, но со случайным выбором стартовой точки на квадрате

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ваш исходный вариант, однако, получен не такими методами, а более хитрым распределением ошибки в соседние точки.

Answer (score 0):

Такой алгоритм реализовать не очень сложно:

- Возьмите исходное изображение и приведите его к размеру, который хотите получить в черно-белых точках.
- Задайте правило по которому точки исходного типа будут превращаться в точки нового типа.
  Например если старая точка была 75% от максимальной яркости, то у новой вероятной быть быть белой будет 75%, а черной - 25%.
- преобразуйте каждую точку исходного изображения в новое.

  ```
  BufferedImage image1 = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  BufferedImage image2 = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {

          int gray = (i + j) + (( i + j) << 8) + ((i + j) << 16);
          image1.setRGB(i, j, gray);
          int bw = 0;
          if (Math.random() * 256 < (i+j)) bw = 0xFFFFFF;
          image2.setRGB(i, j, bw);
      }
  }

  JFrame window1 = new JFrame();
  boolean flip = false;
  BufferedImage image;
  while (true) {
      if (flip) image = image1;
      else image = image2;
      window1.getContentPane().removeAll();
      window1.setTitle("pic");
      JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
      window1.add(label);
      window1.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 200);
      window1.setVisible(true);
      Thread.sleep(500);
      flip = !flip;
  }
  ```

  }

В вашем примере присутствует три цвета, поэтому он выглядит несколько лучше чем чистое преобразование в ч/б.